# What is a "move" opcode in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llc

I am a newbie to `LLVM IR`, and I am trying to simulate some x86 instructions in `LLVM IR`.

Here is a simple case:

```
move %eax, %ebx
```

However, I didn't find any corresponding `mov` opcode after looking at the materials at [here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-copysign-intrinsic) and [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Instruction_8cpp_source.html).

So my question is :

1. If I want to simulate the `mov` opcode using LLVM IR? What should I do?
2. I am new to `LLVM IR`, and probably I would spend a long time on this "simulation" work, what should be the best reference about LLVM IR?

I really appreciate if anyone can give me some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent to the `mov` instruction. LLVM IR is in [SSA (Static Single Assignment) form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), which means that each register is assigned a value exactly once. There are an unlimited number of (virtual) registers -- each operation creates a new one as needed.

It's unclear what you mean by simulating x86 instructions, but if it suits you, you could allocate memory on the stack for a local variable for each register (using the `alloca` instruction), and use the `load` and `store` instructions to copy values between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move the value of one LLVM IR register into another, you can employ `bitcast` instruction:

```
; %a contains 64bit integer value
%a = i64 ...

; Copy / move the value of %a into %b
%b = bitcast i64 %a to i64
```

For more detail, see: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction